# Pelican: join Tags with comma

Tags: python, pelican

I create a static website by Pelican, and currently in the theme the keywords is created from tag, like:

```
{% for tag in articles.tags %}
<meta name="keywords" content="{{ tag }}"/>
{% endfor %}
```

In this case, there will be multiple lines.
What I want is one line with the tag joining by ',', just like: `<meta name="keywords" content="word1,word2,word3"/>`.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i understand it right, Pelican uses Jinja template engine.

So this will do:

```
<meta name="keywords" content="{{ articles.tags|join(',') }}"/>
```

Documentation for this build-in filter: [`join()`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#join)